# Play mp3 audio over http socket on iphone

Tags: iphone, sockets, audio, mp3

I am trying to write an iPhone app that playback mp3 audio streamed by our audio server over http socket. I am just wondering if there is any easy solutions that play the mp3 directly over the socket without any local buffering and conversion?
I found same posts about streaming mp3 files over HTTP connection but with no luck to find anything useful about the socket streaming.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most trivial solution would be the use of `MPMoviePlayerController` for the playback of streaming audio via HTTP.

- [Introduction](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [Alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956847/iphone-streaming-audio-with-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller)

Comment: Hi Till, I finally figured out the Audio Queue is what I need. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

May be what you could do is impliment a mini server on the iPhone here is a [one](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer) then simply stream the mp3 from there